# Why am I getting an error on this line?

Tags: c#, .net

```
float startPos = e.Graphics.MeasureString(toMeasure, f);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(keyword, f, sb, new PointF(e.Bounds.X + (int)startPos, e.Bounds.Y));
```

This is `f`:

```
using (Font f = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 8, FontStyle.Regular))
```

And this is `toMeasure`:

```
string toMeasure = data[e.Index].Substring(0, keywords - 1);
```

The error is on the line:

```
float startPos = e.Graphics.MeasureString(toMeasure, f);
```

The error is:

> *Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.SizeF' to 'float'*

How can I fix it? Since the second line should get float but the first line can't convert from `SizeF` to `float`.

Comment: In general, when you see a Method returns a type or wants particular types as arguments to methods you need to give it what it expects...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the `Width` of the `string` you will have to get the `Width` from the `SizeF` stucture returned from `MeasureString`

Example:

```
float startPos = e.Graphics.MeasureString(toMeasure, f).Width;
```

Answer (score 2):

Method [`MeasureString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx) returns `SizeF` object.

```
SizeF startPos = e.Graphics.MeasureString(toMeasure, f);
```

Comment: Kirill ok but now the second line give an error since it can't convert SizeF to int: e.Graphics.DrawString(keyword, f, sb, new PointF(e.Bounds.X + (int)startPos, e.Bounds.Y)); and if I remove the (int) still error that it can't make + between int and SizeF

Comment: @user2065612, you just want the `Width` from the `SizeF`, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, the [MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/6xe5hazb.aspx) function returns a [`System.Drawing.SizeF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/6xe5hazb.aspx), which is an `ordered pair of floating-point numbers`.